# Can I fetch a file from a remote server from a Putty instance?

Tags: putty, remote-access

I have connected to my remote server using Putty and I want to retrieve a file back to my local machine.  How do I do it?  Can I do it?

Answer (score 5):

PSCP is a part of the putty package.

[Chapter 5: Using PSCP to transfer files securely](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter5.html#pscp)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to get pscp from the same place you got putty from which copies files over the same protocols as putty.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an SSH connection, you can use either PSCP as suggest by Pekka, or [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) is a fairly decent SCP/SFTP client.